# Apache default page is opening when i try to open my ip address

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, django-rest-framework, apache2

Recently i have hosted a webapp in linode using apache2. It was working fine but some thing happened suddenly, it starts opening apache default page when i try to open my webpage. If any one has faced it, can you please help me in getting out of this.

Thank you all.

! https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NOHl.jpg
Previously it was /var/www/html, i have modified to /var/www/html_backup

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.


        ServerName ip_addrs
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html_backup

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: how were you serving the webapp? runserver, gunicorn.... what operating system? Ubuntu?  look in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled to get a starting idea.

Comment: @AMG ubuntu19.0

Comment: @AMG i have django_project.conf in /etc/apache2/site-enabled/

Comment: care to post its contents? redact private stuff. are you using supervisord or some other process manager to start your Django app?

Comment: @AMG i am using sudo services apache2 restart

Comment: @AMG I have edited the conf in my question, please do check it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run the Django app. There are several approaches, I like running the Django app through gunicorn and let Nginx or Apache handle the static stuff and proxy the Django calls through Apache.

It appears to me like you might not be running the app at all right now.  Test it by switching to the root of your project and use the `python manage.py runserver` command. I suspect you had it running somewhere and have stopped it. You'll want to use something other than [runserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server) when you get going.

Comment: decent looking run down at https://coderwall.com/p/ooerda/python-django-apache-ubuntu